# How to model future iPhone application GUI?

Tags: design, iphone

Say you're working on designing the world's greatest iPhone app.

How do you decide what UI would be more effective, would be more intuitive etc? How do you take an idea and decide how to visually represent it?

Do you use any programs (on a mac) to model something like that?

Comment: I'm not the one who downvoted, but this seems like a UX question. http://ux.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I also think UX question.

Comment: It's also very broad and vague. Browse the [User Experience site](http://ux.stackexchange.com) and then try and come up with a specific issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First keep [Apple Human Interface Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/MobileHIG.pdf) under your pillow.
Check also some of the most famous iOS apps and try to learn about their decisions.

But what is really important is to let many people outside of your team to try the application. Because your coworkers will become the masters of how to use the application even it has some flows.

I don't need any program, I use pencil and papers for sketching. This way I can sketch the UI very quickly without dropping tears when I need to get ride of it after spending a lot of time sketching it using a program.

But in case you need a program, check [OmniGraffle](http://www.omnigroup.com/products/omnigraffle/), there are a lot of amazing stencils for prototyping iOS/Android and many other platforms interfaces.

[Tapworthy](http://oreilly.com/catalog/0636920001133) is one of the best books about designing UI no matter what if it is an iOS or and Android app.

> Tapworthy takes you from concept to polished interface design with plain-spoken principles and a rich collection of visual examples for designing exceptional interfaces for the iPhone and iPod Touch.

Answer (score 0):

People are hard to model.  Testing is the best solution.

Mock up the app GUI on paper, or as a small web site if possible, and find people representing your assumed user demographic on which to user test it.  Iterate and improve the fidelity of the prototype or mockup as you go.  When you get enough functionality to be even slightly useful, distribute or even ship several well instrumented prototypes and examine the usage feedback.

Be creative or borrow the best paradigms from any related successful, popular or common products (not just including apps).